# Bash script to convert TUI input to database output not working properly

Tags: bash, script, database, zenity

I have the following Bash script which captures TUI data (zenity) to be prepared for a database insert statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=NULL,2,Van Tassel,NULL,5,6,,8

INPUT="$(echo $INPUT | ( IFS=, read a b c d e f g h ; echo "$a,${b}xxx,$c,$d,${e}xxx,${f}xxx,${g}}
xxx,${h}xxx" ))"

IFS=,; set -f; set -- $INPUT; out=
for i in "$@"; do
    case "$i" in
        "")    echo empty input not allowed; exit 0;;
        NULL)  out="$out,$i";;
        *xxx)  out="$out,${i/%xxx/}";;
        *)     out="$out,\$\$$i\$\$";;
    esac;
done
echo "${out:1}"
```

On running this script I get the following error message:

```
./err.txt: line 4: Tassel,NULL,5,6,,8: command not found
empty input not allowed
```

There are two things wrong with this script and I do not know how to solve them. For one the entry Van Tassel will only work if it is entered as 'Van Tassel' or VanTassel which is not how multiple strings are received from the TUI interface.

The second problem is that the case "") does not work. If I run the same script again but write VanTassel instead of Van Tassel I get the following output instead of the message "empty input not allowed".

```
NULL,2,$$VanTassel$$,NULL,5,6,,8
```

This should not be the case as the 7th field is empty.

Anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `INPUT=NULL,2,Van Tassel,NULL,5,6,,8` is like `foo=bar baz`: run `baz` with `foo` variable being `bar` in the environment. In a shell script you need to quote or escape the space to suppress this behavior.

   In case of a static line, quoting the entire value is often the best solution:

   ```
   INPUT='NULL,2,Van Tassel,NULL,5,6,,8'
   ```

   In the posted code the line is static but in reality "multiple strings are received from the TU interface", right? In such case the solution may depend on how this happens.
2. When you claim the output is `NULL,2,$$VanTassel$$,NULL,5,6,,8`, it's really

   ```
   NULL,2,$$VanTassel$$,NULL,5,6,}
   ,8
   ```

   because in your code there is `${g}}` and a *newline* just after. Next time post the code you're testing or test the code you're posting. :)
3. The case `"")` allegedly does not work because you're injecting `xxx` into the 7th field first! A field modified this way will never match the empty string; it will match `*xxx`. Then you remove `xxx` while building `out` and the field goes back to its original empty value.
4. `echo $INPUT` is very fragile and may give you unexpected results. Unquoted `$INPUT` behaves like [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618): splitting and filename generation (globbing) occur. Note when we use `set -- $INPUT` later, we *do* want splitting and we suppress globbing (`set -f` earlier). But your `echo $INPUT` is prone to both. Even if you use `echo "$INPUT"`, this will still apply: [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) In Bash you can do

   ```
   IFS=, read … <<<"$INPUT"
   ```
5. Use `read -r` unless you know you don't want `-r` (see `help read`).
6. *Maybe* `INPUT` should be `input`. Read this: [naming conventions for variables in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

Comment: Thanks Kamil, sorry for the typo ${g}}. I added `xxx) echo "empty input not allowed"; exit 0;;` to the case statement, so the script works as intended. I have not been able to solve point 1. in your comment but will make separate post on this.